# How I can return a OrderedDictionary in a method?

Tags: c#, .net, ordereddictionary

I want to return an OrderedDictionary in my method, but I have an error with my code...

I don't know why I can't do that:

```
public OrderedDictionary getAllPortsInformations()
        {

            OrderedDictionary SerialPort = filtreXml("/catalog/cd/SerialPort", "SerialPort");
            OrderedDictionary BaudRate = filtreXml("/catalog/cd/BaudRate", "BaudRate");
            OrderedDictionary DataBits = filtreXml("/catalog/cd/DataBits", "DataBits");
            OrderedDictionary StopBits = filtreXml("/catalog/cd/StopBits", "StopBits");
            OrderedDictionary ParityBits = filtreXml("/catalog/cd/ParityBits", "ParityBits");
            OrderedDictionary ReadTimeout = filtreXml("/catalog/cd/ReadTimeout", "ReadTimeout");
            OrderedDictionary WriteTimeout = filtreXml("/catalog/cd/WriteTimeout", "WriteTimeout");
            OrderedDictionary PinCode = filtreXml("/catalog/cd/PinCode", "PinCode");
            OrderedDictionary output = new OrderedDictionary();


            foreach (DictionaryEntry sp in SerialPort)
                output.Add(sp.Key, sp.Value);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry br in BaudRate)
                output.Add(br.Key, br.Value);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry db in DataBits)
                output.Add(db.Key, db.Value);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry sb in StopBits)
                output.Add(sb.Key, sb.Value);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry pb in ParityBits)
                output.Add(pb.Key, pb.Value);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry rt in ReadTimeout)
                output.Add(rt.Key, rt.Value);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry wt in WriteTimeout)
                output.Add(wt.Key, wt.Value);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry pc in PinCode)
                output.Add(pc.Key, pc.Value);

                return output;
        }
```

#### Error message

> Error: Error 1 'application.Xml.getAllPortsInformations ()': all code paths do not necessarily return a value

Comment: What is the error you are getting and what line? Also did you forget `output.Add(pc.Key, pc.Value);` before the return output when posting your example, or is that the error you are getting?

Comment: Is that last foreach statement a typo?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, he's getting it right at the point the last `foreach` is returning output :)

Comment: Are you still getting the error now that you added `output.Add(pc.Key, pc.Value);`? If so, you need to include all of the code in your function, you are leaving out something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last `foreach` loop has nothing in the scope. Either get rid of it or

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry pc in PinCode) { }
```

Comment: Looking at the pattern of code its more likely he forgot `output.Add(pc.Key, pc.Value);` before the return.

Answer (score 0):

Your last foreach does not do anything? Or is that a typo.